# Connect Sql server to php using laravel (php artisan migrate)

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel

1) i make authentication through php artisan make:auth
2) Now i want to migrate user table to SQL servel php artisan migrate

it show this error

SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
 (SQL: select * from sysobjects where type = 'U' and name = migrations)

.env file

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
DB_HOST=DESKTOP-4DE9LKC\SQLEXPRESS
DB_PORT=1433
DB_DATABASE=mah
DB_USERNAME=
DB_PASSWORD=
```

database file

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'sqlsrv'),
'connections' => [
        'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'DESKTOP-4DE9LKC\SQLEXPRESS'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'mah'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', ''),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
        ],
    ],
```

I expect the output table are create in sql server

Answer (score 1):

The SQL Server does not allow you to connect. Either the credentials are wrong or a firewall is blocking the connection to port 1433 on the target machine.

Comment: Thanks Sir, its really helpful